# Echo PHP returned value with AJAX in span/div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Ok I have a following HTML, AJAX and PHP script below. I want to get the `$deduct` value to update `<span id="mywallet"></div>` field when the AJAX request is processed. How can I do so?

Example Form

```
<form>
    <span id="mywallet">$<?php echo $wallet; ?></span>
</form>
```

Example flip-process.php structure

```
<?php
if($_POST){
    //process everything

    $deduct = (something calculated);

    if(success){
       $msg = "success";
    }else{
       $msg = "fail";
    }
}
echo $msg;
?>
```

Ajax Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var dataString = {
            flip: $("#flip").val(),
            amount: $("#amount").val(),
        };
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "flip-process.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: true,
      beforeSend: function(){
                $("#process-flipping").hide();
                $(".coin-flip").show();
      },
            success: function(html){
                setTimeout(function(){
                $(".message").html(html).fadeIn();
                    $("#process-flipping").show();
                    $(".coin-flip").hide();
                },3000);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: whoever downvoted my question.. please have the guts to explain here in comments.. I don't find any reason for it to get downvoted..!

Comment: where does `$wallet` come from?. Not my DV

Comment: Also you might need to post a real code on the server... maybe that is why u got a dv, the code is unreal

Comment: its coming from somewhere.. I am just showing that a PHP variable is there.. my question has nothing to do with this $wallet value here..

Comment: the whole code is 2 pages long.. I don't think I really needed to do it here.. only the structure was perfectly enough for a person with knowledge to understand buddy..

Comment: it does because you wanna update that value... *I want to get the $deduct value to update <span id="mywallet"></div>** and the span u wanna update hv $wallet

Comment: *only the structure was perfectly enough for a person with knowledge to understand buddy*  Good luck with your project

Comment: it came from a SQL query here by fetching the value from the database

Comment: You see? that's an important part, what you need is to update that value in the db with deduction, then after that update was success, u need to run another ajax request to fetch the new value, currently what u trying to do when the page refreshes the new deduct will be lost and old $wallet will show

Comment: no not important... I was looking for an answer like by Lucas below... he did not needed $wallet but gave the solution... Thanks for your free time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, json is the best solution:

```
<?php
if($_POST){
    //process everything

    $deduct = (something calculated);

    if(success){
       $msg = "success";
    }else{
       $msg = "fail";
    }

    echo json_encode(array('status' => $msg, 'deduct' => $deduct));
}
?>
```

and the ajax `success`:

```
success: function(json){
    setTimeout(function(){
    $(".message").html(json.status).fadeIn();
        $("#process-flipping").show();
        $(".coin-flip").hide();
    },3000);
    if(json.status == 'success')
        $('#mywallet').html('$' + json.deduct);
}
```

Comment: and why if(json.status == 'success') condition is here? could you please explain a bit from where and why is it used here?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to use json

PHP

```
<?php

$response = [];

if($_POST){
    //process everything

    $deduct = (something calculated);

    if(success){
       $response["deduct"] = $deduct;
    }else{
       $response["msg"] = "your message here";
    }
}

header("Content-type:application/json; charset: UTF-8");
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var dataString = {
            flip: $("#flip").val(),
            amount: $("#amount").val(),
        };
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
        dataType : "json",
            url: "flip-process.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: true,
      beforeSend: function(){
                $("#process-flipping").hide();
                $(".coin-flip").show();
      },
            success: function(json){
                //json.deduct will has the value you want
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: i know, i have just posted a notice to inform you while i'm writing the code, vote up please

Comment: Thank you @Epodax

Comment: I do have respect for them... thanks @MoustafaElkady :) it works

Comment: however I just took dataType from here.. but thats a great help too.. thanks :)

Comment: @Epodax I am not asking them to code my whole project.. I was stuck at a point where I had no idea HOW TO CODE FURTHER the solution... reason why I googled it but when I did not found it I came to SO to seek a solution on HOW TO CODE that particular thing and where to place it as in my code... SO allows this and I definitely respect them buddy.. thanks